# AJAX request failed with unknown reason (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a service which returns JSON data: http://api.drag2droid.shamanland.com/captcha?base64

I'm trying to execute simple AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "http://api.drag2droid.shamanland.com/captcha?base64",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $("body").html(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("body").html("ajax failed: " + textStatus + ", " + jqXHR.status + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Result is:

```
ajax failed: error, 0
```

But if I just paste this url into address-bar in my browser, I can see json response.

Does somebody knows about possible traps?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shomeser/n5TjL/

**EDITED:**

Actually, I already set up my server-side to allow all requests from any domain with any header, PHP-code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "OPTIONS") {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS"])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS"]}");
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

**EDITED:**

In the Network-tab of Firebug plugin I can see that there is no content retrieved:
[image]

But direct GET-reqeust from a browser shows full content.

Comment: check the network tab of your dev tools, and look at the request, after the ajax call has failed what does it show. If its a crossdomain issue you should have some kind of error in your console.

Comment: Are you running the site and the API on the same domain? I am sure you are aware that AJAX Calls don't work cross-domain. For that you'll have to use `JSONP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all, guys, I found my problem. After I copy-paste code PHP-from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1891118), I decided to optimize it - I placed all statements into `if METHOD == OPTIONS`. This is fault.

Header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be returned not only for `OPTIONS` request.

My updated code works fine:

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]}");
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "OPTIONS") {
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD"])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS"])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS"]}");
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Thanks to @Patrick Evans second comment, but it's already deleted =)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to load a resource from another domain. Because the service you are requesting the JSON from is not configured to allow this, the request is failing.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

When we give the type as "json", the response should be a strict json object. Please verify the response or post it here.

See below the excerpts from the URL: [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

"jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is because of [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (ie., Cross domain issue).  To overcome use [**jsonp**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067472/1671639) instead of json.

```
dataType: "jsonp",
```